# SQL Server table stopped reading from csv suddenly

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, ssms

I have a table in a db in SQL Server that reads data from a csv file that's being uploaded to a ftp each night. The table shows data for the past 30 days, but suddenly it stopped showing entries past a certain date.

I've checked the ftp dump and the csv file - everything here looks fine here (nothing's changed). The table itself is created using SSIS, and I've found various script for extract, load and transform. However, I'm unsure of how and where to start troubleshooting.

I realize that this is somewhat a broad question, so I'm looking for a way or narrowing down the problem?

Comment: Without any details, there's not a lot we can do here. I would suggest debugging the package, it's probably failing at a row. But that is all but a blind guess in the dark.

Comment: Yeah, that was the answer I feared. The packages actually run without errors. However, for some reason the file is not being read. So I'm kind of searching in the dark - and being new to this doens't really help.

Comment: Do you have this DataFlow in any of the Loop container ? If yes then, Are you sure that any folder or the .csv file name format is not modified?

Comment: What is the last date you had it complete with records

Comment: Is the table truncated and reloaded every day or are additional records added afterwards? If it is the former then I suspect that there is a problem with the loading process. If it is the ladder then something may have deleted the data.

Comment: @Srikarmogaliraju - I'm quite sure that nobody touched it. Will try to find out though. Thank you

Comment: @TEEKAY Last record is from Jan 29th. I've tried to track any changes around that time without luck.

Comment: @JWeezy It's the former. The table is truncated each day. I think you're right about the loading part. However can't seem to find the error.

Comment: I would start by adding logging to the package for the OnError, OnWarning, and OnProgress events and see if anything stands out. All of the comments here have some merit but we're just making some educated guesses right now. You may also be able to see what's going on with the "Progress/Execution Results", same row as "Control Flow", "Data Flow", etc when running it in the debugger.

Comment: I would open the package and run it manually in debug mode against a safe server (i..e, dev or test) so as to prevent impacting production. The progress tab will display all log data. Alternatively, if the package is deployed under the Project Deployment model, then just run the All Executions report for the execution ID that failed - this contains all error, warning, and information events that are in the progress tab within Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Every time I had an SSIS issue like this I would open the package and run it manually from within SSIS because I've found the logging at that level better than when it runs as a SQL job.

For large and complicated packages I would have to select parts of and run piece by piece